# Opengl Occlussion Culling not accounting for backfaces properly

Tags: opengl

I am attempting to find the GL_SAMPLES_PASSED in a glBeginQuery(GL_SAMPLES_PASSED, queries) statement for inside an office room render. (So the face normal for the triangles point inwards.)

If I render from top down the roof should occlude the floor...
(But since the normals of the floor point up, and the normals of the roof point down, it shows nothing is occluded and everything passes the glBeginQuery(GL_SAMPLES_PASSED, queries) test.

```
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glViewport(0, 0, mWindow_Width, mWindow_Height);
    drawShapes(); // draw the room


glBeginQuery(GL_SAMPLES_PASSED, queries);
    drawFurniture();
glEndQuery(GL_SAMPLES_PASSED); ///
GLuint available = 0;
glGetQueryObjectuiv(queries, GL_QUERY_RESULT, &available);

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

eveything passes, which should not be the case
The floor and furniture should not pass the glBeginQuery(GL_SAMPLES_PASSED, queries even with the normal pointed down

I am sure I am missing something silly...

Comment: The fact that these are backfaces should be a red herring.  The roof is being drawn, right?  As I understand it, the furniture is *not* visible?

Comment: I don't want to draw the furniture (say looking down) where the roof occludes everything (normals of floor and furniture pointing up and out, normals of roof pointing down, camera orthographic above roof). Currently the furniture and floor are being rendered since glGetQueryObjectuiv(queries, GL_QUERY_RESULT, &available); is returning a ton of passed samples for the floor and furniture. I expect the draw calls for the full furniture geometry and floor not to get triggered if occluded .. .but they are firing, the roof is being rendered, which is should be and the only thing

Comment: Completely ignoring the query for a moment, I don't see a clear answer to @DietrichEpp's question: Just looking at the resulting frame, is the roof hiding the furniture? Or do you still see the furniture when it should be hidden by the roof? Also, you talk about the direction of the normals, but the normals really have nothing to do with things being hidden or not, or with the query result.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you're looking at quick rejection, you should be using *ANY* sampled passed...

Comment: mostly I can see as I step through debugging it the furniture which should be culled is being drawn which is the issue, I'm sure its something with my depth buffer flags etc...

Comment: @Joe: What do you mean by "I can see [...] the furniture [...] is being drawn"?. Is your rendering result wrong? It obvoulsy has to be, if the fragments pass the depth test, as your query suggests. But if the rendering result is wrong, I wonder why you would blame the query to begin with.

Comment: Speaking of silly things, `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);` looks odd to me. You're talking about normals here (they don't directly affect whether something will pass/fail), but polygon winding will, which is probably what you're using to compute your normals. Why are you disabling culling? That's, to me, the reason it's not accounting for backfaces - it's drawing everything regardless of its winding.